# iframe over Silverlight 5 Host blanks out when a Silverligh control gets focused

Tags: html, silverlight

(WORKS FINE ON SL 3 )
I have an iframe displaying some webPages over Silverlight ( the reason for this is tha the Silverlight WebBroswer control doesn't run in Browser unless you apply full trusted mode). 
So this frame displays fine, but if I change a value inside  the iframe HTML content, like typing on text input in that html and then I go and click on some of the silvelright control (anyone) outside the content of my iframe just blanks out, no content on it. But it is weird becuase if the html has links and I mouse over the position where they used to be the iframe displays the HTML content again.

I have the following HTML with it's SilverlightHost div to host Silvelright and I have added an iframe inside the  (frameHost div) below to Host HTML content, I tried first adding the iframe  in the same div where the Silverlight object it, then I placed it into a separate Div to see if that helped but it have the same error

```
#container { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
}
#frameHost,  
#silverlightControlHost { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    text-align:center;
} 

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>


<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="source" value="ClientBin/ShowHtml.xap"/>
                <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                <param name="background" value="white" />
                <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
                <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                    <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
                </a>
            </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
            <div id="frameHost">
              <iframe id="HtmlContentHost"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know why, but accidentally openned a page that host and iframe and so it was working with the controls inside the second iframe, so I came back and adding my content to an iframe and then trying to insert it as the innerHTML for the HtmlContentHost works sweet. so some how a double iframe( which I don't like) makes it works.